# How can I integrate google sign in and firebase in my app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin

I am unable to integrate google sign in my android project. I already integrate the firebase real time database in my project. After that while I integrate the google sign in Error comes-
 "**Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.**
"

Actually while I build project with " compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'" Error comes. I am send my gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.com.realtimedatabase"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'




}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please someone send some solution so that I can fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace or add with your dependencies, below dependencies are for Firebase Authentication and Google SignIn

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

Also, change dependencies for firebase database:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

In your project level gradle update this:

```
dependencies {           
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
    }
```

This happens when you have different versions of Firebase products. Make sure you have everything updated, use Android Studio to update gradle plugins
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sir Now Errors are gone. But I have to Integrate google sign in. Shall I follow the "https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in".

Comment: Yes, that's the best documentation you can follow, also try this - https://medium.com/@nilanyasiru/authenticate-using-google-sign-in-on-android-with-firebase-c893f7eb98b9, it would be great if you accept my answer. Thanks @Kunal Das

Answer (score 1):

Try updating library versions.

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'

and this

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'

Answer (score 0):

After many unsuccessful searches I was able to solve my problem with the following **implementations**

```js
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'
}
```